# Script runs then says no module named package.file.py

Tags: python

I have a package named `package` with `file.py` inside. The structure looks like

```
/package
  __init__.py
  file.py
```

Inside `file.py`, is just

```
print "hello world"
```

When I execute file.py using `python -m package.file.py`,
it runs and outputs `hello world` followed by

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named package.file.py
```

Whats going on here? The code literally runs followed by the error.

Comment: You need to run `python -m package.file` (drop the extension)

Comment: It manages to access `package.file`, when it runs `print 'hello world'` (because you don't guard that with `if __name__ == '__main__':`), but then can't find the module `py` within that.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking Python to load the `py` module located in the `package.file` *package*. You don't have such a module.

But before Python can determine that it doesn't exist, it first has to load the parent packages. So this happens:

```
import package         # succeeds
import package.file    # succeeds, code prints "hello world"
import package.file.py # fails
```

Drop the `.py` part; you don't specify file extensions when loading modules. The following works and won't throw an exception:

```
python -m package.file
```